# How to communicate object of json using blazor c#?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

This is my code here response variable will return the response of the json, now I want to add if statement according to the returned values but its throwing me errors. I tried many things but I don't understand how its done. Someone please help me

```
@code {

    private CountryTracker response;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        response = await HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<CountryTracker>("http://ip-api.com/json/");
    }

    if(response?.country=="Nepal"){
          BlazorTimer timer = new(1000, 35);
        private int secondsLeft = 35;
    }
    else{
          BlazorTimer timer = new(1000, 15);
        private int secondsLeft = 15;
    }
```

Here I want to perform different action according to the json response, how can I do this plese help me. The object of response is country. I want to implement the operation of timer on the basic of country.

Comment: Very unlcear what does (not) work here. Always post full error messages and clearly point to the related code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write statements at the top level of the code. Your logic must go in a method. And instance members (secondsLeft) cannot be conditionally declared in statements. Compare this with your code:

```
@code {

    private CountryTracker response;
    private int secondsLeft;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        response = await HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<CountryTracker>("http://ip-api.com/json/");

        if(response?.country=="Nepal"){
              BlazorTimer timer = new(1000, 35);
              secondsLeft = 35;
        }
        else{
              BlazorTimer timer = new(1000, 15);
              secondsLeft = 15;
        }
    }
}
```